# Input type="month" style the dropdown for pc

Tags: css, html

How can I style the dropdown part of the `<Input type="month">` tag. It works fine on mobile, but on pc + chrome the dropdown thing has an unneeded and confusing date selector. Is there a way to remove it?

Here is a fiddle demonstrating it [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mo5kgqdo/)

Comment: Date selector? I can't see anything. Have you included the necessary JS and CSS for this?

Comment: @ManojKumar Did you use Chrome as stated by the OP?

Comment: Thanks I was on FireFox. What do you want to style @CrowbarKZ?

Comment: Hey, so I was just wondering if it's somehow possible to remove the date-selector which appears in chrome @ManojKumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no much you can do if you want to do it only with `input` tag. As far as I know this is the functionality fully dependent on browser support. In Firefox, for example, it doesn't work at all :-)

I highly recommend to use some JavaScript datepicker which is usually far more independent, like [this one](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). It's API reference is [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

It can be simply used like this:

#### HTML

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

#### jQuery

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Comment: Hey, thx. Didn't know it didn't work in FF. well I guess I have to wait a bit longer till this new tag is supported more consistently

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div className="filterFormField  mt-5">
  <input type="month" name="month" list="monthslist" />
  <datalist id="monthslist">
    <option value="2022-01"/>
    <option value="2022-02"/>
    <option value="2022-03"/>
   </datalist>
</div>
```

In case you need to customize it for the selected datalist.

It can be simply used like this:

JSX:

```
          <div className="filterFormField  mt-5 ">
          <Form.Control
            type="month"
            name="month"
            list="monthslist"
            onChange={(e) => {
              setMonth(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
          <datalist id="monthslist">
          <option value="2022-01"/>
          <option value="2022-02"/>
          <option value="2022-03"/>
          </datalist>
        </div>
```

Comment: add CSS using filterFormField ClassName